# How can I cure the sickened condition without retching?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, conditions, pathfinder-society

I'm playing a Irongut Goblin Rogue (Thief) in society play, who refuses to throw up, because "Food goes in my stomach, not out of it!" This of course causes problems when it comes to the sickened condition, as refusing to retch means I can't use the usual solution. I don't *have* to deal with the sickened condition, because I'm an Irongut and can eat and drink, but it is annoying.

Now the question is, what methods does my character (I can't rely on other characters being in my party as it is PFS) have to cure the sickened condition *without* retching? Magic items are all okay, as long as they are gettable for a PFS character. I'd prefer not to spend feats on a method, but that is doable. Ideally, I'd like a way to deal with it during an adventure, but if not, during downtime works too.

Overall, my priorities are low to no feats used, followed by cheapest method (factoring in repeatability, so let's multiply a hypothetical one use guaranteed cure item's cost by 10 to compare to the cost of a hypothetical reusable cure).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Archetypes

Although likely unpalatable to you, there are two options available through archetypes:

- [Shake It Off](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=139) is a level 2 Barbarian feat accessible with a Barbarian archetype. You'll need to spend at least 2 feats (Barbarian Dedication, Shake It Off). While raging, you may spend 1 action to attempt the save as if you had retched.
- [Greater Mercy](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=232&ArchLevel=10) is a level 10 feat accessible through the Blessed One archetype. You'll need to spend at least 3 feats to access it (Blessed One Dedication, Mercy, and Greater Mercy). It allows you to use Lay on Hands to attempt to remove the sickened condition.

### Boons

If your character is liked by the Horizon Hunters, you may apply the [Wayfinder, Rugged](https://org-play-2e-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/02.4_rewards.html) boon. In short, once per adventure you may reduce the sickened condition by 1.

Comment: There's also a few other options with Paragon Battle Medicine and with No Stranger to Death from the Laswall Sentry Dedication that might be worth mentioning. Not sure about access in PFS for the first option.

Comment: @brandon You are totally right. Those are rare/uncommon though, which make them challenging for Pathfinder Society. I'll check around for options to access them.

Comment: The Rugged Wayfinder should work pretty well. Any other ideas are definitely appreciated though!

Answer (score 1):

(unfortunately, it only works on *adjacent* creatures)

## Advanced First Aid (master Medicine skill feat)

This costs only 1 [skill feat](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2107), and takes 2 actions.
Having *master* in Medicine is not a high price, it is one of the best skills on the game anyway.

Comment: First Aid can only be administered to adjacent creatures, not to yourself. OP could use to cure *other characters'* sickened conditions though.

Comment: You  are  right, I missed this